# Mandarin/Cantonese translation of "it depends on your definition of 'good'"

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

Alice takes Bob to a new steak restaurant.

Alice: Do you think the steak here is good?

Bob: It depends on your definition of "good."

1) What is the natural translation for Bob's statement? 要看妳的好吃的定義 and 就看妳的看法是什麼 feel like English grammar.

2) Is the translation different for Cantonese?

Comment: submit "definition" to iciba:  It all depends on your definition of punk, doesn'tit?

“这全视乎你对朋克摇滚乐的定义，不是吗？->replace 朋克摇滚乐 by "好吃＂

Comment: "depends on your definition of" could be considered  English idiom which even when translated into other European languages might become "depends on how you define", accordingly check  iciba:  It depends on how you define capitalism.

 要弄清什么是资本主义.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “it depends on your definition of 'good'”

The followings could work:

這要看妳對 '好(吃)' 所下的定義是什麼 (M)

噉要睇妳對 '好(食)' 所落嘅定義係乜 (C)

這要看妳心目中 '好(吃)' 的定義是什麼 (M)

噉要睇妳心目中 '好(食)' 嘅定義係乜 (C)

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct colloquial way to express this is probably:

**看你怎么看**.

It literally means:

- 看 = it depends
- 你 = you
- 怎么看 = how [you] see [it]

which gives us something like: that depends on how *you* look at it.