# Is 看怎麼理解? a generalized expression for "it depends" in Mandarin? How about for Cantonese?

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin, cantonese

A movie used the phrase 看怎麼理解 to mean, "it depends."

The context was character A asking character B if something is good or bad. Character B responded with 看怎麼理解.

1) Is 看怎麼理解 a generalized phrase for "it depends?" For instance, can you say 看怎麼理解 if someone asks if a restaurant is good, and you want to say, "it depends?"

2) If not, when can you use 看怎麼理解, and what's a generalized phrase for "it depends?"

3) Is it different for Cantonese?

This question is similar to another one, but not the same. This one is more to understand how 看怎麼理解 varies from other ways to say "it depends" and when 看怎麼理解 is applicable.

Comment: Didn’t you sort of already ask this? And didn’t I sort of already answer it? https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/31224/4136 Albeit, slightly different this time.

Comment: @user3306356 kinda but not really. maybe the question should be rephrased to focus on this specific phrasing. this question is more to understand how 看怎麼理解 varies from your answer and when it's applicable.

Comment: @user3306356 updated with clarification, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

看怎么理解 is okay, but it wouldn’t be appropriate in all cases because 理解 is, in of itself, quite specific.

A more general phrase for 看怎么理解 would be:

> 看你怎么看

(P.S.: adding a 你 in between sounds a lot more natural)

Comment: Thanks for answering (again)! When is 看怎么理解 applicable?

Comment: @Crashalot 理解 literally means “understanding” so - 看你怎么理解 could be understood as “it depends on your unserstanding.” I’m not sure how many situations would call for this kind of phrasage, but it’d pretty specific.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, very useful!

Answer (score 1):

generally, **it depends** is interpreted as: 那得看情况 or 那得看看.

(那得)看怎麼理解 is: *it depends on how you understand it*, which seemingly has been briefed as "*it depends*" in your specific context.